# How to engineer chromosomal duplications?

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, chromosome

Specific genetic engineering of chromosomal aberrations like deletions, inversions and translocations are doable by using the CRISPR/Cas system or the other programmable nuclease systems. Insertions are also possible but mostly limited by the size of the insert.

Here two papers on the topic:

http://www.nature.com/nrg/journal/v15/n5/full/nrg3686.html

http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2014/140424/ncomms4728/full/ncomms4728.html

However these methods appear to be inadequate in case you want to insert a long DNA piece (>1Mb) into a chromosome (in case you want to engineer a duplication).
As far I have understood, problems arise when 1) you want to make such long DNA in the first place and 2) --suppose you have the DNA-- you need to transfect it into the cell...

Does anyone know how to tackle the genetic engineering of a large  chromosomal duplications? Is there any way to induce it without the need of supplementing the extra DNA?